# ClassName::class vs FQN (eg '/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product')

Tags: magento2, resource-model, object-manager

In magento2's code style its mentioned to use ::class. see: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/coding-standards/code-standard-php.html

however in objectManager or resource model initialization i never see this code style in magento's core files. So what is the conclusion here?
Either:
* using ::class is not allowed here, why?
* magento2 is not following their own guidelines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `::class`. Magento applies changes only to new code.

See https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/AbstractAttribute.php#L223 for example.

Comment: tnx Kandy, little bit off topic. but i also see a mixture of FQN usage and short form. Even in the example you linked to. there is a Json::class (ln 209), and FQN Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute::class (ln 223). What is there the recommendation?

Comment: Recommendation to make the code readable. If class name enough to understand code it is no reason to use  FQN